# CGRectContainsRect giving wrong value

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have two rectangles which are defined as follows.

```
CGRect rect1  = CGRectMake(64.000000,1100.500000,704.000000,1971.500000);
CGRect rect2  = CGRectMake(88.000000,1757.416626,100.000000,1780.416626);
```

Now i know that rect2 is contained in rect1 , we can see that from points and it's obvious that CGRectContainsRect should give **TRUE** value. But when i log that value, it is **FALSE**.

```
if(CGRectContainsRect(rect1, rect2)){
   printf("yes1\n");
}else{
   printf("No1\n");
}
```

Upper code is giving false. Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGRectContainsRect` will only return true when one rect is completely contained within the bounds of the second. In your example, the height of rect2 overlaps rect1.

You are looking for `CGRectIntersectsRect`.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct . But from the rectangle which i have used , we can easily see that, rect1 contains rect2.

Comment: rect1 does not contain rect2. rect1's y-points go from 1100 to 3071, rect2's go from 1757 to 3537. The top portion of rect2 spills over past rect1.

Comment: yes, you are correct, Actually i misunderstood the concept of CGRectMack, that's why getting wrong data,Your help is appreciable.